# Why do we need to include support libraries for higher minimum supported android version

Tags: android-support-library, android

Let's say I have an android app for which I am setting android:minSdkVersion="11". I want to use broadcasts in my app and so am using "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager". I am forced to use this because, there is no alternate non-v4 class available.

For compiling, I added the v4 support library jar to my lib dir and everything works fine. Only thing is my application size is bigger due to the included library.

So my question is - is there a way we need not include the v4 library. The support libraries should be included with the android OS itself for higher versions right?

Comment: Should or shouldn't be included is not the point, Google decided not to include it. You have to deal with it and add it yourself hen you wan't to use it. Sorry bud :)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I was looking for a definitive answer to this. So if we want LocalBroadcastManager, we have to include the jar.

Doesn't look right to me though. New functionality should get added in newer versions with support added through support libraries right? In this case, a new functionality is added solely via support library :(